# Can anyone tell me that the error "calling xxxx on bad self" shows

Tags: lua

I use lua in Unity. When I call the function **TryDisableHeadWear **, there are some error I can't understand.
**calling 'GetSurfaceName' on bad self (string expected, got nil)**

```
function def:TryDisableHeadWear()
    if not self:CheckSurfaceName(self._hat_go) then
        self._hat_go:SetActive(false) 
    end
end

function def:CheckSurfaceName(obj)
    local surface_name     = self:GetSurfaceName(obj)
    return head_wear_surface[surface_name] ~= nil
end

local reg = "(%w+)"
function def:GetSurfaceName(obj)
    if not obj then return end
    local root_obj   = self:GetSurfaceObj(obj)
    local surface_obj_name = root_obj and root_obj.name
    return surface_obj_name and string.match(surface_obj_name, reg)
end

function def:GetSurfaceObj(obj)
    if string.find(obj.name, "Surface") then
        return obj
    else
        local parent = obj.transform.parent
        if not parent then return end
        return self:GetSurfaceObj(parent.gameObject)
    end
end
```

Can anyone tell me what the error means?

I try to call the function in normal environment. I get no error and everything goes well. But where are some error report in firebase that means the code above has bugs

Comment: What does your call to `TryDisableHeadWear()` look like?

Comment: What is the full error message including stack backtrace?